# Plot multiple similar data in same graph

Tags: matlab, plot

I wanted to generate a plot (X vs Y), and Z values depend on the Y. The example is shown in the figure below. The matrix size of X is same with Z but not Y. I can plot Z against X, but I wanted to combine all the plot into a single plot and become Y against X. I can plot multiple plots into a single plot but the plot is overlapping each other.

My question is there any method I can merge multiple plots into a single plot without overlapping each plot as the difference between each plot is very small (e.g Z1=1,2,3,4,5 and Z2=1.0001,2.0002,3.0001,4.0002,5.0001). So, I wanted to set each Z plot at different Y axis. (e.g Z1 at Y=0, Z2 at Y=2 ...)

[image]
[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions or idea?

Thank You

Comment: Is Y a cell array or a structure?

Comment: I think is a structure. I have modified the question above to show more details, please have a look.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you highlight the problem you trying to solve? I can't understand what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Greetings all, once again I modified the questions, please have a look.

Thank You.

Comment: So you want to plot `z1`, `z2+1`, `z3+2`, etc. against `x`? Or do you want to have 6 separate axes?

Comment: @CrisLuengo, thank you for the reply. I don't understand what you mean by  z1, z2+1, z3+2, etc. against x. Basically, I wanted X and Y axes. For Y axis will contain all the Z values. I added a figure which all the Z values plot is overlapping, I wanted to plot them separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll clarify the ideas I wrote in a comment.
First, let's get some data:

```
x = 470:0.1:484;
z1 = cos(x)/2;
z2 = sin(x)/3;
z3 = cos(x+0.2)/2.3;
```

I'll plot just three data sets, all of this is trivial to extend to any number of data sets.

#### Idea 1: multiple axes

The idea here is simply to use `subplot` to create a small-multiple type plot:

```
ytick = [-0.5,0.0,0.5];
ylim = [-0.9,0.9]);
figure

h1 = subplot(3,1,1);
plot(x,z1);
set(h1,'ylim',ylim,'ytick',ytick);
title('z1')

h2 = subplot(3,1,2);
plot(x,z2);
set(h2,'ylim',ylim,'ytick',ytick);
title('z2')

h3 = subplot(3,1,3);
plot(x,z3);
set(h3,'ylim',ylim,'ytick',ytick);
title('z3')
```

[image]

Note that it is possible to, e.g., remove the tick labels from the top two plot, leaving only labels on the bottom one. You can then also move the axes so that they are closer together (which might be necessary if there are lots of these lines in the same plot):

```
set(h1,'xticklabel',[],'box','off')
set(h2,'xticklabel',[],'box','off')
set(h3,'box','off')
set(h1,'position',[0.13,0.71,0.8,0.24])
set(h2,'position',[0.13,0.41,0.8,0.24])
set(h3,'position',[0.13,0.11,0.8,0.24])
axes(h1)
title('')
ylabel('z1')
axes(h2)
title('')
ylabel('z2')
axes(h3)
title('')
ylabel('z3')
```

[image]

#### Idea 2: same axes, plot with offset

This is the simpler approach, as you're dealing only with a single axis. @Zizy Archer already showed how easy it is to shift data if they're all in a single 2D matrix `Z`. Here I'll just plot `z1`, `z2+2`, and `z3+4`. Adjust the offsets to your liking. Next, I set the `'ytick'` property to create the illusion of separate graphs, and set the `'yticklabel'` property so that the numbers along the y-axis match the actual data plotted. The end result is similar to the multiple axes plots above, but they're all in a single axes:

```
figure
plot(x,z1);
hold on
plot(x,z2+2);
plot(x,z3+4);
ytick = [-0.5,0.0,0.5];
set(gca,'ytick',[ytick,ytick+2,ytick+4]);
set(gca,'yticklabel',[ytick,ytick,ytick]);
text(484.5,0,'z1')
text(484.5,2,'z2')
text(484.5,4,'z3')
```

[image]

Comment: I think the plot with offset is the 1 I looking for. I don't need the label for the y-axis, just need to add text to z1,z2,.. and is already included in your coding. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest would be to shift Z data. But note that Z2 would look like to be oscillating around 1 - so this is a neat visual representation, but might mislead.

```
% Simple version - shift Z curves by 0, 1, ... (as recommended by @Cris Luengo)
shiftMat = repmat(0 : size(Z, 2)-1, size(Z,1), 1);
Z = Z + shiftMat;

%Min shift up to have non-overlapping - curves touching
for i = 2 : size(Z, 2)
   Zdif = (Z(:, i-1) - Z(:, i));
   Z(:, i) = Z(:, i) + max(Zdif); % + 0.01 to separate them a little bit.
end

%Bigger shift up, to have all points of Z(2) equal or above all points of z1.
for i = 2 : numZ
    Zdif = max(Z(:, i-1))-min(Z(:, i));
    Z(:, i) = Z(:, i) + Zdif;
end
```

Another possibility is to have multiple Y axis and each Z curve plotted against its own Y axis. This is likely fancier and shouldn't mislead, but it is way more work, even after you grab the function, as you still need to position all those axes. MATLAB by default lets you use only 2 axes, so grab a function from fileexchange to add more: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9016-addaxis

Comment: I like how you compute offsets to match the data ranges. But the suggestion for multiple y-axes on the same plot I don't like as much -- it's messy and doesn't help reading the data. Any good data visualization book you'll read will tell you the same thing: if the various data series need different y-axis, they don't belong in the same plot.